# Утечка памяти при изменении размера массива

Tags: c++, массивы, память

У меня есть массив структур, я инициализирую его размер,проделываю с этим массивом какие-то действия:

```
array* arr;
n = 4;
arr = new array[n];
//какие-то функции работающие с массивом
```

а потом меняю размер массива, и получается что один элемент массива отпадает и перестает быть доступным.

```
n = 3;
arr = new array[n];
```

Как я понимаю, происходит утечка памяти. Как ее исправить?

Comment: Как насчет использования std::vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Перед тем как выделять новый массив, освободите выделенную память:

```
array* arr;
n = 4;
arr = new array[n];
//какие-то функции работающие с массивом

delete[] arr;

n = 3; 
arr = new array[n];
```

Но! Это **не** *изменение размера массива*, это создание совершенно нового массива. Да, *случайно* в нем могут оказаться старые данные, но это совсем не обязательно. Элементы нового массива изначально не инициализированы.

В этом же смысле надо рассматривать и утечку - она получается не потому, что "отпал элемент массива", а потому, что выделенная память не освобождена, указатель на нее переписан, и теперь нет никакой возможности освободить эту потерянную память.

P.S. Очень надеюсь, что `array` у вас означает какой-то тип :)

Comment: да, array - это структура